# Rspec - Compare two json values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I got a response from `render json: { success: 'Success' }`, I met a problem when I want to test if the response received the content like this. My unit test is:

```
    let(:success) do
      {
        success: "Success"
      }
    end

    it 'responds with json containing the success message' do
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(success)
    end
```

I got a failure from my test, which is:

```
expected: {:success=>"Success"}
got:      {"success"=>"Success"}
```

I tried to add double quote to `success:'Success'` so that it changed to `'success':'Success'` but still have the same problem. I have two questions, the first is why there's a colon before the success, and the second is how could I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.parse` will have string-y keys by default.

```
my_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
p my_hash.keys.first.class # String
```

If you want it to symbolize the keys,

```
my_hash = JSON.parse(response.body, symbolize_names: true)
p my_hash.keys.first.class # Symbol
```

Note: the option is called `symbolize_names` and not `symbolize_keys`.

Remember that a symbol is not a string:

`p :success == 'success' # false`

Comment: Thank you, that works! Could you see my other question about RSpec if you have a chance? I appreciate it!    The is the [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132089/rspec-how-to-test-activerecordrecordnotfound)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to test API response with JSON format. You could try `json_spec` gem with many other helpful features https://github.com/collectiveidea/json_spec