# rspec - How to test ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a method to update people's attribute, and it will rescue `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if the people cannot be found. The method is:

```
  def update
    @people= People.find(params[:id])
    if @people.update(people_params)
      render json: { success: 'Success' }
    else
      render :edit
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    render json: { error: 'Failed') }
  end
```

And I want to test the situation when the record not found, here's my test for now:

```
    let(:people) { create(:people) }
    let(:people_id) { people.id }
    let(:user) { people}
    # Other tests...
    context 'when person not found' do
      let(:exception) { ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound }

      # What should I write so that I can let the record not been found?

      before { allow(People).to receive(:find).and_raise(exception) }

      it 'responds with json containing the error message' do
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq({error:'Error'})
      end
    end
```

I want my test executed under the condition that records not found. But I don't know how to do it. I tried to set `let(people) {nil}` but it not work. Is there an anyway to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Why is your test not working? It looks fine to me

Comment: Isn't is a typo? Your class is `People`, not `Person`.

Comment: you're also missing the request, or r u doing it in some bedore/let ?

Comment: Thank you guys, I just find the solution, the way to make the record not found is to change the people's id to an un-exits one.

Comment: usually you do not need to rescue `RecordNotFound` error in controller because of DRY principles. You can define it in the parent controller

Answer (score 5):

This is not a good solution to begin with. In Rails you want to use `rescue_from` to handle common errors on the controller level.

```
class ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

  def not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :404 }
    end
  end
end
```

This lets you use inheritance to DRY your code.

```
render json: { error: 'Failed') }
```

Is an anti-pattern. If the request failed you should tell the client by sending the correct HTTP status code.

If you want to test that your controller handles a missing resource correctly you would do:

```
let(:people) { create(:people) }
let(:people_id) { people.id }
let(:user) { people}

it "returns the correct response code if the person cannot be found" do
  get '/people/notarealid'
  expect(response).to have_http_status :not_found
end
```

This does not use any stubbing and actually tests the implementation.

Answer (score -3):

you can try :

```
let!(:error_failed) { { error: 'Failed' } }

context 'when people is not found by params' do
  it 'return 404 and render json failed'
    null_object = double.as_null_object
    allow(People).to receive(:find).with(params[:id]).and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new(null_object)

    put :update, format: :json, .....
    expect(response.body).to error_dailed.to_json
    expect(response.status).to .....
  end
end
```