# How to check if the inside method has been called using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I got a method to update the person by id:

```
def update_person(id)
  handle_exceptions do
     person = Person.find(id)
     #...other
  end
end
```

When this id doesn't exist, the handle_exception should be called. But how could I test it? The test I wrote is:

```
context 'not found the proposals' do
  subject {controller.send(:update_person, 3)}

  before do
    allow(Person).to receive(:find).and_raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
    allow(subject).to receive(:handle_exceptions)
  end

  it 'calls handle_exceptions' do
    expect(subject).to have_received(:handle_exceptions)
  end
end
```

But it not works, I got a failure said:
     Failure/Error: expect(subject).to have_received(:handle_exceptions)

```
   ({:message=>"Not Found", :status=>:not_found}).handle_exceptions(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

The `handle_exceptions` method is

```
def handle_exceptions
  yield
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  flash[:warning] = 'no record found'
  Rails.logger.error message: e.message, exception: e
  @error_data = { message: 'no record found', status: :not_found }
end
```

Comment: The `handle_exceptions` method is _always_ called. It _wraps_ the database lookup. Can you show the _content_ of the `handle_exceptions` method though? What is the method definition?

Comment: you are mocking allow(subject).to receive(:handle_exceptions), so I don't see why Person should receive find.

Comment: @maxpleaner hi max, I have add the ```handle_exceptions``` into my question

Comment: You appently really did'nt read or understand my answer to the very simular question you asked a week ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132089/rspec-how-to-test-activerecordrecordnotfound

Comment: Rather than testing that `handle_exceptions` was called, I would check that `@error_data` is populated and possibly that `Rails.logger.error` is called as well

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling the method under test in the subject block.

```
subject {controller.send(:update_person, 3)}
```

This is actually called before the example runs and before the `before` block.

```
context 'not found the proposals' do
  before do
    allow(subject).to receive(:handle_exceptions)
  end

  it 'calls handle_exceptions' do
    controller.send(:update_person, "NOT A VALID ID")
    expect(subject).to have_received(:handle_exceptions)
  end
end
```

But as far as tests go this one is not good. You're testing the implementation of `update_person` and not the actual behavior. And you're calling the method with `update_person.send(:update_person, 3)` presumably to [test a private method](https://anthonysciamanna.com/2016/02/14/should-private-methods-be-tested.html).

You should instead test that your controller returns a 404 response code when try to update with an invalid id. Also why you insist on stubbing `Person.find` is a mystery since you can trigger the exception by just passing an invalid id. Only stub when you actually have to.

Comment: Thank you, I do read your answer on my another question, as your advice, I'll test if my controller returns a 404 response

Answer (score 0):

After couple days working, I realized the reason I'm confused about it is I didn't figure out about 'who called this function', and I think it's the most important thing to know before test it. For the method like this:

```
class User::Controller
  def methodA
      methodB 
  end

  def methodB
     // ...
  end
```

The mistake that I made is I thought the methodB is called by methods, but it's not. It's called by the controller, and that's the reason that I can't make the test works. There's so many things need to learn, and I hope there's one day that I won't have a mistake like this and be able to help others.